# C# Radix Sort implementation in LinkedList

Tags: c#, singly-linked-list, radix-sort

i have a task to make a radix sort algorithm for a linkedlist class, i have an object "Info", which has int Year and double Price, i need to sort linked list by Year using radix sorting.

```
    class Info
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public Info() { }
        public Info(int y, double p)
        {
            Year = y;
            Price = p;
        }
    }
```

```
    class Node
    {
        public Info Data { get; set; }
        public Node Next { get; set; }
        public Node(Info data, Node adress)
        {
            Data = data;
            Next = adress;
        }
    }
```

```
    class LinkedList
    {
        private Node First;
        private Node Last;
        private Node Current;
        public LinkedList()
        {
            First = null;
            Last = null;
            Current = null;
        }
     }
```

And i have taken radix sort algorithm for integer from this [site](https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/searching-and-sorting-algorithm/searching-and-sorting-algorithm-exercise-10.php). Problem is, i don't know how to modify it to work with my linked class.

```
        static void Sort(int[] arr)
        {
            int temp = 0;
            int i, j;
            int[] tmp = new int[arr.Length];
            for (int shift = 31; shift > -1; --shift)
            {
                j = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
                {
                    bool move = (arr[i] << shift) >= 0;
                    if (shift == 0 ? !move : move)
                        arr[i - j] = arr[i];
                    else
                        tmp[j++] = arr[i];
                }
                Array.Copy(tmp, 0, arr, arr.Length - j, j);
            }
        }
```

How to make it work with my linked class ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on that code, arr and tmp would need to be linked lists. One issue with this approach is that moving a node requires keeping track of the previous nodes in order to move a node. A dummy head node could be used to provide a node previous to the first data node, or special case handing when moving a node to the start of a list. An alternative would be using two pointers (references) to nodes of temp lists, one where bit == 0, one where bit == 1, and then concatenating the two temp lists into a single list. Note this approach takes 32 passes. If the radix sort were based on a byte instead of a bit, it could be reduced to 4 passes, but would need 256 pointers to nodes for 256 lists.